# 3ds max export animation to gif

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax

New to 3ds max!.

I have a scene with a car which is animated prom position 1 to position 2,
I want to export the top view of this animation into jpegs or gifs so I can use it in a 2d environment.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a script or for the buttons to push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press f10, set an output path, choose a file type, check your animation range and hit the big button below that says render, when in doubt press f1.

Answer (score 5):

1) Select the view you want render in the perspective viewport
   -easily do this by clicking the view cube on the view you want

2) Press F10 to open the render setup
   - Note: leave the time range output at single for now 
 A - In the time output roll out choose the desired time range and the timing, eg "every nth frame"
   - In the area to render roll out - select view
   - In the Output size enter the width and height of the out put image
   - In the Render Output rollout click the "Files" button and choose where you want the file saved
     and the format you want to have rendered. If you are trying to render out frames for an
     animation you may want to select jpeg or png format.

3) Be sure that you select the appropriate renderer in the Assign Renderer roll out

4) From the create menu in the top menu bar select create camera from view
   - This will ensure that you can get back to the exact same view if you need to rerender

5) Press shift Q or click the render button to do a test render.
   - if you are happy with the image position and size in the rendered frame great! If not
     hold your middle mouse button down and drag the image around to position it correctly.
     If you need to zoom in or out use the camera "dolly control" in the botom right corner of 
     the screen. Run another test render and if your happy your ready for step 6.

6) Go back to step 2 and set up the Time Output rollout as suggested

7) You probably have had the overwrite file message popup a few times by now!
   Again press Shift Q or click the render button and bobs your uncle!

Note:Remember that you want to output textures in sizes that are a multiple of 2 eg 256,512,1024
     if you plan to use these textures in a game. If you are using them in a paint program to create 
     sprite tiles remember that some game engines allow a max size of 2048 pixels.

Good luck with your project! I'm always glad to share knowledge and help people out.